# Hero Card - Singin Button not opening pop-up window

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Have tried the following code to create SignIn button and on clicking it tried openup a popup window. Not sure of why it is not working.

```
var message = {"attachments":[{
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
"content": {
"title": "Hero Card",
"subtitle": "Subtitle",
"text": "Text",
"images": [
{
"url": "https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/apps/teams_dev_app_largeimage.png"
}
],
"buttons": [
{
"type": "signin",
"title": "Sign-IN",
"value": "https://bots.teams.microsoft.com/uswe-01/v3/WhoBot/auth/initiate?state=H4sIAAAAAAAEAI2RTU7DMBCFTVbQBWfoBsTGSePa-VshVSrqlt8NEpo44zZSYgfbbcUhuRPTcoFuRnp-79Mb279XjCWrHViLw6Zj14yxMUSEMbCE9C3pXFW1KgqpTpPNXskkJ1k5e0AfIPbOkv48Jesml1BLU7U8F2i4hGXNq5KGXEpTqkIKje2XrkyuOyi4AqO4XLSGQ22WXBgQeVsK6Dp83NvvdNsOaZhAI22z9u7Uy6mnapzf9t1FZSx5RQs2EnpHqKmEWnRSciiBkE4SolrN6Y64wFx1lRJstglP3u0nljyj7qcez_gD4aJqLlmeJS_oD73GNz-we-J2MU6hybIwtpBGD8b0egQLW_SpxZjBiD6jVX8m_P8DDIHM8ytHqmc3dHjcuTmM857N3mHYU3ATPnDQbsT14I4U-AOd1xCazQEAAA2&amp;tid=Legacy-Operation-Id-63cf8623-b7b5-4594-a789-5dcb5464f77a&amp;width=300&amp;height=250"
}]
}
}]}
print(JSON.stringify(message))
```

Comment: why are you using a hero card and not an oauth prompt?